# How to apply shipping rules promotions

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, shopping-cart

I have setup different shipping methods in my store and I want to offer 3 promotions with 3 different coupon codes wherein:

Promo 1: ORDERS over $25 get free Priority Mail shipping upgrade
Promo 2: Order $99+ and 2day shipping is on us
Promo 3: Order $125+ and overnight shipping is on us

I am new to Magento and as per my research, I have seen that extensions will solve this but also want to know if there's a no-cost method on how to do it?

Thank you very much,

Mara

Answer (score 3):

**Free Shipping Promotions**

Free shipping can be offered as a promotion, with or without a coupon. A free shipping coupon — or voucher — can also be applied to “customer pick-up” orders where there is no shipping, so the order can complete the workflow by being invoiced and “shipped.”

Some shipping carrier configurations let you set a minimum order for free shipping. However, shopping cart price rules let you create complex conditions based on multiple product attributes, cart contents, and customer groups.

After you create a new price rule, it takes an hour or so for it to become available. Be sure to allow enough time for it to get into the system. Then, test the rule to make sure that it works correctly.

[image]

**To set up a free shipping promotion:**
Before you begin, enable the Free Shipping method in your store’s configuration. Then, complete the free shipping settings for any carrier services you want to use for free shipments.

On the Admin menu, select Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules.
Follow the steps below to set up the free shipping promotions you want to offer.
When complete, click the Save Rule button.

Wait an hour or so for the rule to become available. Then, test the rule to make sure it is working correctly.

**Free Shipping for Any Order
Free Shipping for Orders Over $Amount**

[image]